# How to request grunt serve from host machine?

Tags: networking, gruntjs, virtual-machine

Trying to setup angular on a virtual machine with yeoman to avoid breaking my machine with the packages management.

After generate the project with `yo myproject`, install angular globally & locally, install grunt with bower and more dependencies, I'm able to run the server using `grunt serve`

The `localhost` is accessible from the VM via `wget localhost`, but it does not load from the host.

I've tried modifying the file `/etc/network/interface` to [static address](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7709293/) and accessing the static IP from a browser, and also to [set dynamic DHCP](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7709292/) with port forwarding

[image: host:3090; guest:9000]

None have worked, the browser can't make a connection:

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at

I would like to upload more useful files/output to give more context, but as a new grunt user I have no idea where to look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set connect-middleaware listen on 0.0.0.0 ip address to ensure host accessible.

You can edit your Gruntfile.js like this.

Find `connect` task in `grunt.initConfig({});` change the hostname in the `options` to `0.0.0.0`

It should look like this:

```
// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: [
        '.',
        'examples'
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

run `grunt serve`, try to use vm ip to access ip from host. it should available.